# Apply CSS StyleSheet to HTML document in webview in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a HTML document rendered from Server Side in Xamarin WebView.
I want to apply CSS Stylesheet to the HTML document in webview.

```
using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                string response = (new StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
                ArticleData article = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArticleData>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArticleDetails>(response).d);
                var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
                htmlSource.Html = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Assets/Main.css' /></head><body>" + article.Html + "</body></html>";
                webView.Source = htmlSource;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the css is inside the Assets. Due to i did not have the `article.Html`, i created a `local.html` in Assets folder for reference.

local.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>webViewSample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
<p>This is a local Android Html page</p>
<img src="XamarinLogo.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Main.css:

```
html,body{margin:0;padding:10px}
body, p, h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

Use the dependency service to load the CSS and html file from the Assets folder.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace App27.Droid
{
public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "file:///android_asset/";
    }
}
}
```

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
   
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    <WebView x:Name="webView"  HeightRequest="500"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
  public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        htmlSource.Html = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Main.css' /></head><body>" + " <p><a href='local.html'>next page</a></p>" + "</body></html>";
        htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
        webView.Source = htmlSource;
    }
 }
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOGuJ.jpg